# Доступ к имени и ссылке таксономии в node.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal

Возникла необходимость получить доступ к имени и ссылке таксономии в файле `node.tpl.php` (Drupal 7).

Кто нибудь может помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел способ. Вытаскивает только название.

```
function get_taxonomy_term()
{
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    if ($node != NULL) {
        return $node->field_category['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name;
    }
}
```